# Client side validation for model attribute Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-core

Help me to validate(client side validation) model attribute using asp.net core mvc.

```
 Public class Ticket{

        [StringLength(150), Required] 
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required] [RegularExpression(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z+\.]*[a-zA-Z] {2,4}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid {0}")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using Ticket model and binding ticket model to html.Html is as below

```
 <label asp-for="Name">Name</label>
                            @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(x => x.Customer.Name).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;", @class = "form-control",  }))
                            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>

<label asp-for="Email">Email</label>
                            @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(x => x.Customer.Email).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;", @class = "form-control"}))
                            @*<span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>*@
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Customer.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

But here it is not validating an email input or Name input length. And in html markup their is no required attribute or max-length attributes. Below is Html Markup

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Name">Name</label>
                        <input class="k-textbox form-control" id="Customer_Name" name="Customer.Name" style="width:100%;" value="">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
```

Html markup is generated without any required attribute or regex pattern for email.

I am missing anything?. Help me out what i need add more for client side validation.

Comment: Looks like you are using Kendo UI for your HTML. Look at  https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/validation to see what data annotation attributes are supported.

Comment: Do you include `<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />` on your page?

Comment: No i am not using @AntonToshik